# Create an object instance with annotations manually in TYPO3

Tags: annotations, typo3

In a controller in TYPO3 CMS 6.2, is it possible to create an instance of an object with all annotations activated? For example, the following won't work:

```
$mapper = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\PropertyMapper();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface
 * @inject
 */
protected $objectManager;

$instance = $this->objectManager->get('Your\Class\Name');
```